# Struggling with queries through Django M2M field

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have these models, with a M2M field from WordCloud to Source through WordCloudSouce

```
class Source(Model):
    source_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="foobar")

class WordCloud(Model):
    cloud_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cloud_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, unique=True)
    sources = models.ManyToManyField(Source, related_name="sources", through='WordCloudSource')

class WordCloudSource(Model):
    wordcloud_sources_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    wordcloud = models.ForeignKey(WordCloud, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to construct a query that finds a `wordcloud` that has `cloud_name='frank'` and `sources` as a list of strings (e.g `['a', 'b']` or `['a']`).

I am looking for something like:

```
WordCloud.objects.filter(cloud_name='frank', sources=['a', 'b'])
```

but I am unclear how to write a query that traverses the `sources` M2M field to get a list of the associated sources for a `wordcloud`. I have read through the Django docs for 3.0, and it still is not making any sense to me.

The behavior I want is as follows. Say we have the following:

- `w1` = `Wordcloud` object with `name=frank` and `sources=['aa']`
- `w2` = `Wordcloud` object with `name=frank` and `sources=['aa', 'bb']`

The query `filter(name='frank', sources=['aa'])` should only match `w1`.

The query `filter(name='frank', sources=['aa', 'bb'])` should only match `w2`

I got as far as

```
WordCloud.objects.filter(cloud_name='frank', sources__source_name__in=['aa', 'bb'])
```

But it is not correct as it returns wordclouds named `frank` with both `sources=['aa']` and `sources=['aa', 'bb']`, which is not what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't understand what behavior you expect. Do you want to filter `WordCloud` objects named `frank` and with sources that are equal to `aa` OR `bb`?

Comment: Not exactly. Say `w1` = `Wordcloud` with `name=frank` and `sources=['a']`, and `w2` = `Wordcloud` object with `name=frank` and `sources=['a', 'b']`. I want the query `filter(name='frank', sources=['a'])` to only match `w1`, and the query `filter(name='frank', sources=['a', 'b']` to only match `w2`.

Comment: I update the original post to make the behavior I expect more explicit.